# More than one ForeignKey from same Model

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filters

I have a model Analytics

```
class StoreAnatytics(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    tax_sum = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0, verbose_name="tax sum"
    )
```

which has a ForeignKey to model Store:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, default="", verbose_name="store name")
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=MARKET, default=Amazon, verbose_name="store type")
```

Now I need to add a filters to my Analytics. The problem is that I have to filter by 2 fields: store (store pk) and type (store's type). I tried to add to my Analytics model a second ForeignKey field (type) from Store model. But I get:

```
ERRORS:
<class 'stores.admin.StoreAnalytics'>: (admin.E202) 'dashboard.StoreAnatytics' has more than one ForeignKey to 'stores.Store'. You must specify a 'fk_name' attribute.
dashboard.StoreAnatytics.type: (fields.E302) Reverse accessor for 'dashboard.StoreAnatytics.type' clashes with field name 'stores.Store.type'.
HINT: Rename field 'stores.Store.type', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'dashboard.StoreAnatytics.type'.
dashboard.StoreAnatytics.type: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'dashboard.StoreAnatytics.type' clashes with field name 'stores.Store.type'.
```

my filters.py looks like:

```
from dashboard.models import StoreAnatytics
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters


class StoreAnatyticsFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    store = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr="exact")

    class Meta:
        model = StoreAnatytics
        fields = ["store"]
```

But I need a field "type" in it.  How can I solve this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class StoreAnatyticsFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    store_id = filters.NumberFilter(field_name='store__id', lookup_expr="exact")
    store_type= add same as for type beacuse i dont know choices are integer or string
    class Meta:
        model = StoreAnatytics
        fields = ["store_id", "store_type"]
```

Comment: This can't help, because I have no "type" field in model StoreAnatytic. First I have to add it.

Answer (score 0):

so, the problem was very easy:
I needed to add related names in model and add fk_name in admin.py.